# Flutter flip widget from side not middle

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm trying to create a animation for widgets which would make them flip. I've found snippets online but they all flip the middle, I want to flip from the extreme left or right[image]

Comment: Like a book page?

Comment: yes, exactly like that

Comment: hope this helps..https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/page_turn

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple fix. If you already have a Transform widget that can do the image above, the alignment property of the widget is probably set to `Alignment.center`, change this to `Alignment.centerLeft` or `Alignment.centerRight` to flip from right to left or left to right respectively

```
...
child: Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()...,
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: ...,
        ),
);
```